# How to hide List Item in Custom List based on a Field Value

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need a way to hide an entire list entry from a group if a value of a field = Security.

For example if I have a list of Client Contracts and everyone can see them, but I enter a Field Value of "Security" then only the Management Group can see these, so when the other groups view the items in the list those Contracts would be hidden from them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to do this would be to change the default view of the list by including a filter to exclude the 'security' items and then on a web part page, add two webparts pointing to the custom list.

The first webpart would display the new default view you created and then use audience targeting to display it to the security group with your users in it.

Change the web part settings in the second web part only by editing the view within the web part and removing the filter. Using audience targeting, assign that one to your management security group.

This will prevent snoopy people from going in and changing the view within the custom list because the only unfiltered list is within the web part targeted to your managers.

You'll also need to make a change to the permission level for your users. To ensure them not being able to create ANY view within the custom list, remove the ability to make personal views.

Comment: This worked perfectly and actually solved another part of the puzzle for us! Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but couldnt users navigate to the list directly and change to a different view (the one meant for managers for example)?

Comment: Because the view is only created in the actual webpart and not the list, there is no way for them to navigate to it from within the list. Using this method, you're also restricting the ability for users to create personal views on the list so they can't access the data through that way either.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options (assuming it is sharepoint 2010, in Sharepoint 2013 you have to jslink for limit the view of the row)

- Target Audience
- View
- Permission (set with workflow)